# Generate all non-isomorphic non-bipartite connected graphs of order n

Tags: c, graph-theory, sage

I know that [nauty](https://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) can generate n-vertex [bipartite graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) (`!geng n -c -b`), but I haven't seen a corresponding command for its opposite (non-bipartite graphs). (I might have missed it.)

**SageMath** provides a way to **filter graphs** as follows:

```
 s=[g for g in graphs.nauty_geng('-c 6') if g.is_bipartite()==False]
 len(s)
```

> 95

But I would like to ask if there is a closer approach to `nauty`, such as using a **C** version to obtain non-bipartite connected graphs. That's because nauty is implemented in C.  Alternatively, is there a direct algorithm for generating non-bipartite graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I asked Brendan McKay, he told me this can works.

```
pickg -~b
```

Besides, `pickg`  can do many things.

```
              Constraints:

              Numerical constraints (shown here with following  #)  can  take  a  single  integer
              value,  or  a  range  like #:#, #:, or :#.  Each can also be preceded by '~', which
              negates it.   (For example, -~D2:4 will match any maximum degree which is _not_  2,
              3,  or 4.)  Constraints are applied to all input graphs, and only those which match
              all constraints are counted or selected.

       -n#    number of vertices     -e#  number of edges

       -d#    minimum degree         -D#  maximum degree

       -m#    vertices of min degree -M#  vertices of max degree

       -r     regular                -b   bipartite

       -z#    radius                 -Z#  diameter

       -g#    girth (0=acyclic)      -Y#  total number of cycles

       -T#    number of triangles    -K#  number of maximal independent sets

       -H#    number of induced cycles

       -E     Eulerian (all degrees are even, connectivity not required)

       -a#    group size  -o# orbits  -F# fixed points  -t vertex-transitive

       -c#    connectivity (only implemented for 0,1,2).

       -i#    min common nbrs of adjacent vertices;     -I# maximum

       -j#    min common nbrs of non-adjacent vertices; -J# maximum
```